# Wepback require from variable

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am making console utility which accepts a path to configuration file as a console argument.

F.e: utility -f /path/to/file.js

I need to require this file to read configuration. Is it possible to handle this with webpack? As I understand context can not help me in this situation.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm already using webpack.

P.S Solution is to use something like:  eval('require')(dynamicPath)

Comment: I don't think you need webpack just for this - you should be able to require it after you access `process.argv`

Comment: I'm already using webpack in this project. I just need to require config file.

Comment: Ok - I'll add a more comprehensive explanation in an answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Webpack can only do a dynamic require like this if the file to be required is available at compile time. For example, if you require a "dynamic" file path, like

```
require('./assets/images/' + someVariable + '.png')
```

Then under the hood, Webpack will include **all** images matching that pattern in the bundled require code. It basically will include all files matching the regex:

```
/.\/assets\/images\/*.png/
```

I would probably try putting the config file in a specific folder, and using require on that folder:

```
require('./configs/' + process.env.CONFIG_NAME);
```

This way Webpack will only include all files in the `configs` folder.

The Webpack documentation is **horrible** but there is more information [on the dynamic requires page](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html).

Comment: Ah.. I was even trying to make something like
let load = require;
load(dynamicPath);
But it is smart enough )

Comment: This helps: eval('require')(dynamicPath)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in a config file as an argument to a node process, it will be accessible in the [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) array of command line arguments. I don't know if you are using some other framework (like the excellent [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)) to help with making command line programs, but we can just slice the array to find what we need.

To resolve a path from the directory the script is launched in, you can use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) - this returns an absolute path to the working directory of the node process.

Finally you can use `path.resolve(processPath, configPath)` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)) to generate a path that is always guaranteed to resolve to the config. You can then require this path.

You probably need to do this first. The top of your file could look something like this:

```
/* relevant require() calls for necessary modules */
var path = require('path');

// first two arguments are node process and executed file
var args = process.argv.slice(2); 

var configIndex = args.findIndex('-f') + 1;
var configPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), args[configIndex]);

var config = require(configPath);

/* the rest of your code */
```

Comment: I don't believe this is related to the question, which concerns building a dynamic file path into a webpack bundle

Comment: The question refers to making a console utility which takes the config file path as an argument, and how to require this within your code - or so it seems to me. Of course it depends on what the utility is doing, and what the config is for.

Comment: Yeah the problem is more about there is no trivial way to write require(filePath) with webpack. It is always trying to resolve this path, which results into context.